# Cordova - 'Cordova/CDVURLRequestFilter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, cordova, crosswalk

I have a problem with building iOS app with Cordova. I'm using Crosswalk with Cordova plugin. After running `cordova build` in terminal, I'm getting error message:

```
Plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/CDVNavigationWhitelistPlugin.h:23:9: fatal error: 
      'Cordova/CDVURLRequestFilter.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDVURLRequestFilter
```

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: did u get any solutions to this?

Comment: @sharmacal I added solution for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was older version one of the plugins, that I've installed with Cordova-Crosswalk.

So it can be fixed in two ways - by updating everything (plugins etc.) or by simple installing again Cordova-Crosswalk via npm in different folder.